# Software to remove hiss noise from the videos

Tags: video, noise-cancelling

I am looking for a software that can edit hiss noise from my videos.
Please do not suggest audio software, I'm looking for video formats like `avi` files.

Comment: You *know* that there is software to extract the audio part from an avi and to re-integrate the cleaned audio?